# Codepen modernizr.js - 404 Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, codepen

I'm using Codepen modernizr.js over 1 years. Suddenly it started showing error 404. That means the file does not exist but I don't think Codepen like website stop like this stuff without any notification because lots of peoples are using it.

```
Javascript location was [http://codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js][1]

Example: [http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/FgIBC][2]
```

**If that script will not work anymore then anyone has the idea to get back that Modernizr.js?**

Thank you!

Comment: http://markup.tips/tips/loading-modernizr-from-a-cdn-with-a-local-fallback.html may help

Comment: I tried but it's not working @AnilKumar :-(

Comment: I found it. That's here [https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modernizr](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modernizr) ;)

Comment: good to know, still your problem is open in case they again changed it :), so you look for CDN fall-back technique, i have given the link my previous comment to make this future proof.

Answer (score 2):

**I send an email to Codepen.oi about this issue and they replied:**

> Hi Chinmay,
>
> Thanks for writing in! The CodePen-hosted link to Modernizr is no longer supported. You can still get Modernizr for your Pens, though :) Start typing "Modernizr" in one of the External JavaScript fields and you can select it from the typeahead menu.
>
> If you need Modernizr for your own website, you can get a hosted link at: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modernizr
>
> Thanks for using CodePen!